# How to create new Set Redis?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, redis

I do subtraction of two redis sets like as:

```
items = r.sdiff("apps", "apps_2")
```

And after try to create new set:

```
r.sadd("apps_diff", items)
```

But get error.
How can I create new set?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: you need to add each element one by one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `*` operator to unpack the list of arguments for the function call.

```
 items = r.sdiff("apps", "apps_2")

 r.sadd("apps_diff", *items)
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists